# Whonix, how to connect to a Wifi?

Tags: wifi, virtualbox, networkmanager, whonix

I'm running Whonix through Oracle Virtual Box, inside Windows 8.1., and I'm trying to configure it to connect to the internet.

On Windows I am currently connected to my WiFi.

I have both the Whonix Gateway and the Whonix Workstation opened; on the lower right edge there is an option on the menu to enable the network adapter(s), both on the Gateway and on the Workstation; 
Despite the fact that I enabled them, I cannot see any available WiFi.

Could you tell me how to **connect** to a **WiFi** through **Whonix**?

I cannot find it on the documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. It's totally unrelated. Whonix uses whatever internet connection the host operating system (in this case: Microsoft Windows) provides. Whonix does not mind about wired connection vs wifi. It's neither required, and recommended against to change VirtualBox network settings. Neither network settings inside Whonix VMs need to be changed.

The only thing that may require configuration are bridges. Applies to users that are in countries / have internet service providers that block connections to the Tor public network.

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Bridges